# can't extract tar.gz file

Tags: linux, tar, gzip

I used backup.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
cd /home/sebastien/save

tar -zcvf backup.$NOW.tar.gz /var/www/Symfony/
```

in /home/sebastien/save i have:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root      root         45 nov.  10 15:50 backup.11-10-2015-15-50-01.tar.gz*
```

i'm trying to extract this file with :

```
tar -zxvf backup.11-10-2015-15-40-01.tar.gz -C /home/sebastien/tmp/
```

but Nothing is happening /home/sebastien/tmp is empty!

Comment: The archive is 45 bytes long, so it's probably empty. What was the output of `tar -zcvf backup.$NOW.tar.gz /var/www/Symfony/` ? Any error messages?

Comment: Now it's ok cause in my bash file i had an another cmd that blocked process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing that other command which blocks the process.